# Tidyverse: Replacing entire strings based on partial matches

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I'm looking to replace entire string entries within data based on partial matches using functions in the `stringr` package.

The only method I've tried has been replacing exact matches using `str_replace_all()` but this becomes tedious and unwieldy when there are dozens of variations to correct for. I'm looking to replace based on partial matches. In my reprex below, I replace variants of "Spaniard" and "Colombian" by direct specification. However, I would love to perform those replacements based on something like meeting the condition that "Spa" or "Col" exists in the words.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data <- c(
  "Spanish",
  "SPANIARD",
  "Spainiard",
  "Colombian",
  "Columbian",
  "Ecuador",
  "Equador",
  "Ecuadorian",
  "VENEZUELAN"
)

str_replace_all(data,
                c(
                  "Spanish" = "Spaniard",
                  "SPANIARD" = "Spaniard",
                  "Spainiard" = "Spaniard",
                  "Columbian" = "Colombian"
                ))
#> [1] "Spaniard"   "Spaniard"   "Spaniard"   "Colombian"  "Colombian" 
#> [6] "Ecuador"    "Equador"    "Ecuadorian" "VENEZUELAN"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

So `str_replace_all()` works as advertised, but I'm looking for a way to streamline this process in the tidyverse. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use a distance measure (e.g., Jaro-winkler's distance, or some other distance measure), but they do have their drawbacks. Be weary of what you could be changing with partial matching. If you are doing partial matching it would be wise to see what the possibilities are. But, you can do what you outlined in tidyverse using `case_when` with `startsWith` or `grepl`:

```
tibble(data = data) %>%
  mutate(
    v1 = tolower(data),
    new_name = case_when(
      startsWith(v1, "spa") ~ "Spanaird",
      startsWith(v1, "col") ~ "Colombian",
      startsWith(v1, "eq") | startsWith(v1, "ec") ~ "Equadorian",
      startsWith(v1, "ven") ~ "Venezuelan",
      TRUE ~ as.character(data)))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  data       v1         new_name  
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 Spanish    spanish    Spanaird  
2 SPANIARD   spaniard   Spanaird  
3 Spainiard  spainiard  Spanaird  
4 Colombian  colombian  Colombian 
5 Columbian  columbian  Colombian 
6 Ecuador    ecuador    Equadorian
7 Equador    equador    Equadorian
8 Ecuadorian ecuadorian Equadorian
9 VENEZUELAN venezuelan Venezuelan
```

To see the possibilities you can do this (or several other things):

```
tibble(data = data) %>%
  arrange(data) %>%
  count(tolower(data))
```

Comment: I've only just learned about the existence of the distance measure concept. Any recommendations on how I may learn how to apply it in R?

Comment: Hey @ChrisAguilar, I would start with the documentation for `stringdist`, and there are a couple distance measure in `RecordLinkage` too.  I don’t have too many reccomedations other than the papers they cite / Wikipedia that I have looked through though. Sorry I am not more help but good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use distance method for partial matching

```
vals <- c("Spaniard", "Equador", "Colombian", "Venezuelan")
library(stringdist)
vals[amatch(tolower(data), tolower(vals),maxDist=5)]
#[1] "Spaniard"   "Spaniard"   "Spaniard"   "Colombian"  "Colombian"  
#[6] "Equador"    "Equador"    "Equador"    "Venezuelan"
```

---

It can be piped in a `tidyverse` work flow

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(v1 = data) %>%
    mutate(v1 = vals[amatch(tolower(v1), tolower(vals), maxDist = 5)])
```

Comment: So by simply creating a character vector with the desired values and applying  `amatch()` as above, the corrections get applied. That's great! Are there any drawbacks to this method, or common instances when it will fail? Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisAguilar Yes.  It is based on distance method, so if your matching elements vary too much, then you may have to increase the `maxDist`