# R: Match first three characters for every value in a column to a list, replace with value from list

Tags: r, regex, string, loops, match

The following data is part of my data set

```
data$country <- "República Dominicana", "Mexico", "México", "Uruguay", "Haiti", "El salvador", "MÉXICO", "Panamà", "Mexxico", "México, Chile, Colombia.", "Haiïti", "Argentina", "Costa Rica", "Colombia/Argentina/Uruguay", "www.unac.edu.co"
```

I have created a list of the unique countries like so

```
countrynames <- c("Argentina", "Bolivia", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "El Salvador", "Guatemala", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Mexico", "Nicaragua", "Panama", "Peru", "Uruguay")
```

I've determined that it's enough to match the first three characters for the vast majority of cases to the countrynames list. Now what I want to do is run it so that if the first three characters match, then it replaces the cell's values with the countrynames value. For the life of me, though, I can't figure this out. Does anyone have a good way to do this? I don't even know how to begin to approach it, and I've spent some time looking at different solutions on here that only seem to cover cases where you want to match whole words to other values in lists.

## UPDATE

I ended up doing it like this: not super efficient, but it got the job done:

```
  data$Country <- data %>%
  mutate(
    v1 = tolower(prac$Country),
    Country = case_when(
      startsWith(v1, "arg") ~ "Argentina",
      startsWith(v1, "bol") ~ "Bolivia",
      startsWith(v1, "col") | startsWith(v1, "www") ~ "Colombia",
      startsWith(v1, "cos") ~ "Costa Rica",
      startsWith(v1, "rep") ~ "Dominican Republic",
      startsWith(v1, "ecu") ~ "Ecuador",
      startsWith(v1, "el s") ~ "El Salvador",
      startsWith(v1, "gua") ~ "Guatemala",
      startsWith(v1, "hai") ~ "Haiti",
      startsWith(v1, "hon") ~ "Honduars",
      startsWith(v1, "mex") | startsWith(v1, "méx") ~ "Mexico",
      startsWith(v1, "nic") ~ "Nicaragua",
      startsWith(v1, "pan") ~ "Panama",
      startsWith(v1, "per") ~ "Peru",
      startsWith(v1, "uru") ~ "Urugay",
      TRUE ~ as.character(prac$Country)))
```

Based it [a lot off of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240930/tidyverse-replacing-entire-strings-based-on-partial-matches/56241284)

Comment: I immediately see an edge case here, because `República Dominicana` will never match to `Dominican Republic` using on the first three letters.

Comment: That's fine for me. The point isn't to get them all, the point is to reduce the list so that I only have to address a few of them manually. The above list is just a snippet of the overall list. For example, one of them is a website - I'm not going to be able to address that through this. But I can get maybe 95-99% just by matching the first 3 characters, and that already vastly reduces my workload.

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
A = c("Brazil", "France", "Belgium") 
B = c("Belgien", "Brasilien", "Frankreich") 
X = data.frame(A, Short = substr(A, start = 1, stop = 3)) 
Y = data.frame(B, Short = substr(B, start = 1, stop = 3))
```

Then we can use an inner join to bring those together according to the first three letters.

```
Result = inner_join(X, Y) 

> Result
    A       Short      B
 1  Brazil   Bra  Brasilien
 2  France   Fra Frankreich
 3 Belgium   Bel    Belgien
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Not quite - what I want to do is replace the wrong/misspelled values with the correct ones by looking them up with the first three characters (for most of the cases, the first three characters will match the correct values and I'll be able to hand the rest manually). Although I guess this could work if there were a step after replacing the original column with the new one? It's also not the case that there is an equal number of countries - I have many more Mexico than Chile, for example, so I would need the lengths to be able to be different.

Comment: Just think of `A` as the misspelled ones and `B` as the correct spelled ones. After the inner join you can just drop the columns `A` and `Short` and keep the correct ones in `B`. The number of countries is not important here. It is only important that you have the correctly spelled name of all countries for the inner join to work.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I'll give it a go and see how it works. Appreciate your help!